CSV Produced by Google Script is Not Updated When Triggered?
I have a google script that calls an API every day. When I run the script manually it overwrites the current files in my google drive with the most recent daily data from the API. I have set up a trigger to run the script every morning. When I look at the execution log is says the trigger executed without, when I look at the activity on google drive it says the file was overwritten, however when I look at the data itself it is not updated. If I run the script manually the data will be updated?
I tried to see if there were any errors but there were none.
The google script is below
function Air_Quality_Data() {
  // API key and other parameters
  var apiKey = 'DE376407-F84F-46DB-9FCC-BBBB19A48EEA';
  var zipCode = '10010';
  var distance = 25;  // Adjust the distance if necessary

  // Initialize a variable to store the combined CSV content
  var combinedCsvContent = '';
  var headerIncluded = false;  // Flag to track if the header has been included

  // Loop through the last 90 days
  for (var i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
    // Calculate the date for each day
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - i);
    var dateStr = Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    
    // Construct the API URL for each day
    var url = 'https://www.airnowapi.org/aq/forecast/zipCode/?format=text/csv&zipCode=' 
              + zipCode + '&date=' + dateStr + '&distance=' + distance + '&API_KEY=' + apiKey;
    
    // Fetch the data from the API
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    
    if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
      Logger.log('Data for ' + dateStr + ': Fetched successfully.');
      
      // Get the CSV content for the day
      var csvContent = response.getContentText();
      
      // Split the content into rows
      var rows = csvContent.split('\n');
      
      // Append rows to the combined content, skipping empty rows and headers after the first one
      for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
        if (rows[j].trim() !== '') { // Check if the row is not empty
          if (!headerIncluded) {
            // Include the header from the first file
            combinedCsvContent += rows[j];
            headerIncluded = true;  // Set the flag to true after including the header
          } else if (j > 0) {
            // Skip the header and only include data rows
            combinedCsvContent += '\n' + rows[j];
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('Failed to fetch data for ' + dateStr + '. HTTP Status code: ' + response.getResponseCode());
    }
  }
  
  // Folder ID where you want to save the file
  var folderId = '1NrAOYee2AGyCTdC8i7I2zBPZjERGQTIM';
  
  // Get the folder by ID
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  
  // Define the file name for the combined CSV
  var fileName = 'NYCDailyAirQualityData.csv';
  
  // Search for an existing file with the same name in the folder
  var files = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);
  
  // If the file exists, overwrite its content
  if (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.setContent(combinedCsvContent);
    Logger.log('Data overwritten: ' + fileName);
  } else {
    // If the file does not exist, create a new one
    folder.createFile(fileName, combinedCsvContent, MimeType.CSV);
    Logger.log('New file created: ' + fileName);
  }
}


I've tested your code, both manually and using a Time-driven trigger (custom time), and it works under both. As a matter of interest, you've tagged "google-drive-API", but all the commands are standard DriveApp. Would you please explain why the API tag? Would you also confirm details of the trigger?

Also tested with Time-driven very 10 minutes - works fine. Can I suggest some trouble-shooting: insert some code (I can supply) to parse the data and save it to your spreadsheet. This way you can compare the results of manual execution with timed-execution.
